# Getting the value on every page usertype in Django

Tags: python, django

I don't know how can I prevent using Global variable to pass data to another function. It's too much hassle to create `request.session` on every page just to get the value set by another function. I know there's a way e.g using decorators etc. but I haven't found yet the best way on how to implement it. Can anyone help me? Below I been using Global variable in usertype `request.session['type_user'] = usertype`. Thanks for the help.

```
def example_login(request):
   usertype = "Admin"
   request.session['type_user'] = usertype 
   return redirect ('dashboard')

def dashboard(request):
   value_usertype = {'usertype_var':request.session['type_user']}
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', value_usertype)
   
def anotherview(request):  # too hassle to create another request.session in every page
   value_usertype = {'usertype_var':request.session['type_user']}
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', value_usertype)
```

Comment: It looks quite odd to store this in the session, normally this is something that you store in the user accounts. Django already has `Groups` for this and the `Permission` framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution that uses class based views?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Im mistaken about my title above and I already changed it, I think there's nothing wrong in permission and I already used groups I just wanted to get the usertype in every pages in a shorcut way like decorator I guess?

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt I appreciate your response how can I used class based views? Is this like a decorator?

Comment: Checkout @WillemVanOnsem's answers, it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Function-based view

You can construct a decorator that will pass the `usertype_var` to the view function:

```
from functools import wraps

def with_usertype(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs, usertype=request.session.get('type_user'))
    return wrapped
```

You can then use the decorator as:

```
@with_usertype
def dashboard(request, usertype):
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', {'usertype_var': usertype})

@with_usertype
def anotherview(request, usertype):
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', , {'usertype_var': usertype})
```

You can also restrict it with:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def restrict_usertype(*restrictions):
    def mydecorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
            usertype = request.session.get('type_user')
            if usertyp in restrictions:
                return f(request, *args, **kwargs, usertype=usertype)
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
        return wrapped
    return mydecorator
```

then you can restrict this with:

```
@restrict_usertype('Admin')
def dashboard(request, usertype):
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', {'usertype_var': usertype})

@restrict_usertype('Admin', 'Other')
def anotherview(request, usertype):
   return render(request,'dashboard.html', , {'usertype_var': usertype})
```

## Class-based views

For class-based views, since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) you can make use of the [**`setup(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup). This method normally sets the `request`, `args` and `kwargs` to the view object:

```
# since Django-2.2
class UsertypeMixin:

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usertype = request.session.get('type_user')
        return super().setup(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args,
            **kwargs,
            usertype=self.usertype
        )
```

Then the mixin can be used, for example in a `ListView` with:

```
class MyListView(UserTypeMixin, ListView):
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # use self.usertype
        # …
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
```

we can restrict this as well with:

```
# since Django-2.2

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class UsertypeRestrictMixin(UsertypeMixin):
    required_usertype = ()

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().setup(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.usertype not in self.required_usertype:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return result
```

and then use this as:

```
class MyListView(UsertypeRestrictMixin, ListView):
    required_usertype = ('Admin',)
```

## Django's groups and permissions

However often a better modeling is using groups, since a user can often have multiple roles. It can be a commentator, administrator, author, etc. and often after a while users can have multiple roles. Django has a system of [groups and permissions [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) for this in place.

The advantage of using permissions is that this is more *fine-grained*, so one can make permissions for each (type of) view, and furthermore it allows a person to be a member of multiple groups, and also thus obtain the permissions of all these groups. This makes it more flexible since sometimes you want to give a small set of users an extra permission.

Comment: I appreciate for your response and ideas, but I'm getting an error Function-based view in decorators  that you provided `usertype=request.session.get('type_user'))' the request is not define , then I tried to fix it just putting request like this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrWyv.png) but now the problem is [Ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hITbW.png) do you know where is wrong?

Comment: @Jason_Dy: sorry, made a typo, should be fixed now.

Comment: Im been mistaken about my question including "restrict every pages"  and I already updated it. There's nothing problem in restriction in every page, besides  I really like your idea , Function-based view decorators, but it gives me an error those Screenshot I provided previously

Comment: It is possible in usertype decorator value?  to have more than one value like this one? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJiMp.png) thanks

Comment: thanks for your response Im so glad, but did you mean you updated in Function-based view? I mean I want to put all my request.session in decorators not in views.py that's why I want to have more than one value usertype in decorators like this one  [link[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJiMp.png) .It is possible?

Comment: @Jason_Dy: yes, you decorate with `@restrict_usertype('Admin', 'Other')`, so you can use an arbitrary number of "roles".

Comment: @Jason_Dy: there was also a small typo `restriction` -> `restrictions`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rely on Django's auth system for both authentication (username + password = user1) and authorization (can user1 user this view?)

### Using Django's auth system:

- Login:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

- Logout:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

- Limiting access for authenticated users

  - redirecting to login

  ```py
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

  @login_required
  def my_view(request):
      ...
  ```

  - redirecting to custom template

  ```py
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

  @login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field')
  def my_view(request):
      ...
  ```
- Limiting access for authorized users

  - based on roles (Django's recommended approach)

  ```py
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

  @permission_required('your_app.admin_rigths')
  def my_view(request):
      ...
  ```

  - based on groups (custom way)

  ```py
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

  def is_admin(user):
      if your_custom_verification_for_admin_rights:
        return True
      return Fa

  @user_passes_test(email_check)
  def my_view(request):
      ...
  ```

See more in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

### Custom auth approach

You can also not make use of Django's approach, as I needed once. I did the following:

- Create an authentication middleware

```
class CustomAuthMiddleware:
  def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
    # do your custom verification
    user_type = get_user_type_function(request)
    
    # add its result to the request object
    request.__setattr__('type_user', user_type)

    # go to normal request flow
    return self.get_response(request)
```

- Add it to settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  ...django's middleware

  'your_auth_app.path.to.middleware.CustomAuthMiddleware',
```

- Create a decorator for authorization enforcement

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def needs_user_type(user_type):
  def auth_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            authorized = False
            if hatattr(request, 'type_user'):
              request_user_type = request.__getattribute__('type_user')
              authorized = request_user_type == user_type

            if authorized:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return PermissionDenied()
        
        return wrapper

    return auth_decorator
```

- Use the decorator in your views

```
@needs_user_type('Admin')
def dashboard(request):
   # do stuff

@needs_user_type('Admin')
def anotherview(request):
   # do stuff
```

If you want to access `user_type` in your views, see Django's Request Context

Comment: Thanks for your response, Im been mistake about my question  above  and I already updated it. There's nothing problem in restriction in every page and I used the way your custom approach through groups in decorators. The only problem is how can I avoid using 'request.session' in every pages. I guess it works on decorators

Comment: I believe what solves your need is adding a custom context_processor then. Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext